# Check for Valid/Active URLs before download - Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, http, curl, laravel-7

I'm trying to check download images and store locally in my assets folder. 
Before start downloading, I want to check and make sure the link is still live.

I only want to start my download if the link is live `200` Ok.

## Try #1

```
public function handle()
{
    $skills = Skill::all();

    if($skills != null){

        foreach($skills as $i=>$skill){

            if (strpos($skill->img_path, 'http') !== false) {
                if(!isset($exception)) {

                    //update the path in DB
                    $image_path      = '/assets/fe/img/skill/';
                    $img_name        = $skill->name.'.png';
                    $path            = public_path() . $image_path . $img_name;
                    $uploadSuccess   = file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($skill->img_path));

                    // dd($uploadSuccess);

                    if($uploadSuccess) {
                        $skill->img_path = $image_path . $img_name;
                    }

                }

            }

            $skill->save();

        }

    }
}
```

---

I seems to get so many issues

One of them is

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: thumbsplus.tutsplus.com

Another one is

> file_get_contents(https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

What is the cleaner way ? Please suggest, I will try now.

---

## Try #2

```
public function handle()
{
    $skills = Skill::all();

    if($skills != null){

        foreach($skills as $i=>$skill){

            if (strpos($skill->img_path, 'http') !== false) {

                $file_headers = @get_headers($skill->img_path);
                if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
                    $exists = false;
                }
                else {
                    $exists = true;

                    if(!isset($exception)) {

                    //update the path in DB
                        $image_path      = '/assets/fe/img/skill/';
                        $img_name        = $skill->name.'.png';
                        $path            = public_path() . $image_path . $img_name;
                        $uploadSuccess   = file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($skill->img_path));

                    // dd($uploadSuccess);

                        if($uploadSuccess) {
                            $skill->img_path = $image_path . $img_name;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            $skill->save();

        }

    }
}
```

---

## Try #3

```
public function handle()

{
    $skills = Skill::all();


    $failCount = 0;
    $successCount = 0;


    $failList = [];

    if($skills != null){

        foreach($skills as $i=>$skill){

            if (strpos($skill->img_path, 'http') !== false) {


                $file_headers = @get_headers($skill->img_path);
                if(!$file_headers || strpos($file_headers[0], '404') !== false) {
                    $exists = false;
                    $failCount++;

                    array_push($failList,$skill->name);
                    // break;
                }
                else {


                    $exists = true;
                    $successCount++;


                    //DEBUG
                    // dd($file_headers[0]);


                    if(strpos($file_headers[0], '200')) {

                        //update the path in DB
                        $image_path      = '/assets/fe/img/skill/';
                        $img_name        = $skill->name.'.png';
                        $path            = public_path() . $image_path . $img_name;
                        $uploadSuccess   = file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($skill->img_path));


                    // dd($uploadSuccess);

                        if($uploadSuccess) {
                            $skill->img_path = $image_path . $img_name;
                        }

                    }


                }

            }

            $skill->save();
            echo ".";
        }

    }


    echo "\r\n";

    $this->info('=========================');
    $this->info('Success :'. $successCount);
    $this->info('=========================');
    $this->info('Fail    :'. $failCount);
    $this->info('List    :'. print_r($failList));
    $this->info('=========================');

}
```

## seems to work

but it hang, sometimes more than 1 minute, at a certain `dot`

```
⚡️  php artisan skillIcons:download                                                                           
..............................................................................................................................                                                                                                                  
=========================                                                                                               
Success :12                                                                                                             
=========================                                                                                               
Fail    :7                                                                                                              
Array                                                                                                                   
(                                                                                                                       
    [0] => GitHub                                                                                                       
    [1] => Geolocation API                                                                                              
    [2] => Xcode                                                                                                        
    [3] => Protractor                                                                                                   
    [4] => Sketch                                                                                                       
    [5] => Amazon ECR                                                                                                   
    [6] => WinSCP                                                                                                       
)
List    :1
=========================
```

All images seems to be downloaded successfully

```
⚡️   ls public/assets/fe/img/skill/
AWS Console.png         Digital Ocean.png       Javascript.png          PayPal.png              Terminal.png
AWS.png                 Disqus.png              Jest.png                Photoshop.png           TextMate.png
Alimofire.png           Divvy.png               Jira.png                Pod.png                 TextWrangler.png
Amazon ECS.png          Docker.png              Kamar.png               PostgreSQL.png          Transmit.png
Amazon RDS.png          Duet.png                LESS.png                PyCharm.png             Twitter.png
Angular.png             EC2.png                 Laravel Elixir.png      Python.png              Ubuntu.png
AngularJS.png           Evernote .png           Laravel.png             QuickBooks.png          VMWare Fusion .png
Apache.png              Express.png             Linode.png              React Native.png        VS Code.png
Atom.png                Facebook.png            Mac OS X.png            Realm.png               Vagrant.png
Bash.png                Final Cut.png           Markdown.png            Redis.png               Virtual Machine.png
BitBucket.png           FusionCharts.png        MobaXTerm.png           RequireJS.png           Virtualbox.png
Bower.png               GitLab.png              Mocha.png               S3.png                  Webpack.png
CKEditor.png            Go Daddy.png            MySQL.png               SAML 2.0.png            Windows.png
CSS.png                 Google Chart.png        NPM.png                 Salesforce.png          Wireshark.png
Camtasia.png            Google Map.png          Navicat Premium.png     Sass.png                Word.png
Cent OS.png             Google Translation.png  Nginx.png               Secure Shell.png        Yarn.png
Chai.png                Gulp.png                Node.png                Selenium.png            iMovie.png
Chat.io.png             HTML.png                Noteability.png         Shopify.png             iOS.png
Coda.png                Heroku.png              OAuth 2.0.png           SinonJS.png             jQuery.png
CodeBox.png             Illustrator.png         Open  Stack.png         Siteground.png
Composer .png           Instagram.png           OpenID Connect.png      Sublime Text.png
Confluence .png         J Player.png            PHP.png                 Swagger.png
```

---

## 3 seconds

How do I decrease the wait time to only `3` seconds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle error in some way.
You can try

```
try {
    ...
} catch () {
    ...
}
```

But I prefer doing things this way

```
public function handle()
{
    Skill::get()->map(function($skill){
        if(strpos($skill->img_path, 'http')) return;
        $img = $this->getImageFromUrl($skill->img_path)
        if(!$img == null) return;

        $image_path      = '/assets/fe/img/skill/';
        $img_name        = $skill->name.'.png';
        $path            = public_path() . $image_path . $img_name;
        $fp = fopen($path,'x');
        fwrite($fp, $img);
        fclose($fp);

        if($uploadSuccess) {
            $skill->img_path = $image_path . $img_name;
            $skill->save();
        }
    });
}

public function getImageFromUrl($url){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); // The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2); // The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute

    $img = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);

    if($err) {
        echo $err;
        return null;
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $img;
}
```

I refactored some code and if you prefer this keep it if not get only logic and do it as you prefer

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`active_url`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-active-url) validation rule to check if the given URL is alive. According to the docs:

> The field under validation must have a valid A or AAAA record according to the `dns_get_record` PHP function. The hostname of the provided URL is extracted using the `parse_url` PHP function before being passed to `dns_get_record`.

```php
if (validator([$skill->img_path], ['active_url'])->fails()) {
    // URL is not valid/active
}
else {
    // URL is valid/active   
}
```